# load texture in a class before proceeding

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have presented a simple example to illustrate what my problem is. in functions it's easy to use await async to make sure textures are loaded before proceeding with the program. if I want to work with classes because of the cleanliness of the program, I have no idea how I can do this so that the constructor waits until the texture is loaded before the subsequent function is called.

```
//in my three.js init function
var sphereObject = new Sphere(100, texture);
var sphere = this.sphereObject.sphere;
scene.add(sphere); 
//------------------------


class Sphere{
  constructor(radius, preloadedtex){
 
    //this.material = this.doSomething(preloadedtex); this work fine

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load("grass.png", function(texture){
      this.material = this.doSomething(texture);
    });    
    const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 128, 64 );
    this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, this.material); 

  }

  doSomething(texture){
    //further operations with the texture before the function returns a material

    return material;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextureLoader has an `onLoad` callback as the second argument of .load(). This is taken [directly from the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=textureloa#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader):

```js
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
   'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg',

    // onLoad callback
    function ( texture ) {
        // in this example we create the material when the texture is loaded
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            map: texture
         } );
    },

    // onProgress callback currently not supported
    undefined,

    // onError callback
    function ( err ) {
        console.error( 'An error happened.' );
    }
);
```

Comment: I passed an already loaded texture to the class for testing and it works as it should. the thing with the callback sounds very good, but it probably sounds easier than it seems. I tried the code with callback (see modified code) but I only get a black screen